# How to define a generic constructor in typescript under inheritance?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, design-patterns, constructor

I am using typescript and want to write a factory function to create a new object instance and provide an array of properties to be filled. Basically a converter from an existing object to a new instance of another (related) type. It should be used like this

```
const newA = A.from({ a: 1 });
const newC = C.from({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 9 });
```

I have this working (member variables omitted for clarity and Object.create could be simpler, see below for the reason)

```
class A {
  static from(data: Partial<A>) : A {
    const o = Object.create(A);
    Object.assign(o, data);
    return o;
  }
}
```

This works nicely as long as I inherit from this class. I do not want to recreate this function anytime like so

```
class A {
  static from(data: Partial<A>) : A {
    const o = Object.create(A);
    Object.assign(o, data);
    return o;
  }
}

class B extends A {
static from(data: Partial<B>) : B {
    const o = Object.create(B);
    Object.assign(o, data);
    return o;
  }
}
```

The following snippet works, but I need to specify the class when I call it twice

```
class A {
  ...
  static from<T extends A>(data: Partial<T>) : T {
    const o = Object.create(this);
    Object.assign(o, data);
    return o;
  }
}

const newC = C.from<C>({ ... });
```

and want to use some form of generic, i.e. I imagine something like this.

```
class A {
  static from<T extends this>(data: Partial<T>) : A {
    const o = Object.create(this);
    Object.assign(o, data);
    return o;
  }
}

const new C = C.from({ ... });
```

I would guess that this is theoretically possible, since at compile time the context of the static function is known and you could infer the class type, but I did not figure out on how to use this inherited type in the signature definition.

Is this a good (acceptable) pattern and if not, what should I do?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [polymorphic `this` types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) for static methods, but they are not currently supported in TypeScript.  There's an [open feature request for it, microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) but I don't know if it will ever be implemented.

Luckily there are workarounds, one of which is mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863#issuecomment-410887254): use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) method in which the [`this` parameter](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) depends on the generic.  For example:

```
class A {
    static from<T extends A>(this: new () => T, data: Partial<T>): T {
        const o = new this(); // no-arg constructor
        Object.assign(o, data);
        return o;
    }
}
```

Here we will only allow `from()` to be called on objects which are no-arg constructors of some subtype of `A`, and they will return this subtype.  I changed the implementation from `Object.create(this)` to `new this()` just to show that we care about the "no-arg-ness" (after all, a subclass called with `Object.create(this)` that required a constructor argument is likely to fail to construct a valid instance).

So then this works, since `B` is a no-arg constructor of `B` instances:

```
class B extends A {
    foo = "bar";
}
const b = B.from({}); // B
console.log(b.foo.toUpperCase()); // BAR
```

but this fails, since `Z` is not a no-arg constructor of `Z` instances:

```
class Z extends A {
    constructor(public bar: string) {
        super();
    }
}
const z = Z.from({}); // error!
// -----> ~
// typeof Z is not assignable to new () => Z
console.log(z.bar.toUpperCase());  // error at runtime, z.bar is undefined
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa7oQC5iwS2GgDMAnAewFsAeAFWgFMAPLegOwBMZYA+ACiwAWeCAC5oregHdovAJTQAvN2g0ANNHa4wYgApgS+MCFrdZYusjQZrwMq2zQyi8VOiDhcgNzQA9D-FkALT6AObQtvZYJACuwFhkJKjW1gDyAEYAVvRxAHSQEHghrLxk6po4sp5Jyegk9FjRJKyOVVboAL6onWiooPnQAEIMzGyccIjV6ERkTgrQAERp+vOt3REOac4DOaSUvAjtlb7+A712EGQg9DkgZCG8aTszOfEAqgAO7-QkAMKQ9HIjn5BrAAEqoCEoPpQaAALWGLA4XAmbXC5yisXiJF472iaRABGgSxIYmwJDwrBC8ksNXQEGiX2xlUm0G6a3R0AAXs5YTtyBR9odvMDvuQSABCVDAwIymXKAB+Uv8WAAnl8yEQ4dBhAEsNB8oVWGB8fQ3E4JNI5IplLCzvZLtdbvdOTliS8yB9GX8IADZEdjgwSGL9XqYqx8BR6OoXcTtTBohx6EQKfR2EA)

Comment: That was insanely enlighting! Thank you. I am still struggeling as to why you can add the this parameter to the signature and it is ignored in the function call? Is this a special type of parameter?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It’s called a “`this` parameter” and I’ve linked to the relevant documentation in my answer.  Here’s the link again: [`this` parameters](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters)