# TypeScript static member returns same class instance?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

How to declare return type for `find` method?

```
class Base{
  find(){
    return new this()
  }
}
```

As `find` returns self class instance it cannot be hardcoded as `:Base`. For example If I inherit `Child` class from Base than Child.find() must return `Child` type, not `Base`.

```
class Base{
  static find(): Base{  // this is incorrect
    return new this()
  }
}
```

I have tried to use generic like below but got TS2302 error. So what is the correct way to do this?

```
class Base<T>{
  static find(): T{  // ERROR: TS2302
    return new this()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the answer to [the question this duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774804/how-to-define-a-generic-constructor-in-typescript-under-inheritance), there is currently no [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) for `static` methods or members in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) for more information.

The workaround is to make the static method generic and give it a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters):

```
class Base {
    static find<T extends Base>(this: new () => T): T {
        return new this(); // no-arg constructor
    }
}
```

This should behave as you want:

```
class GoodSub extends Base {
    foo = "bar";
}
const goodSub = GoodSub.find(); // GoodSub
console.log(goodSub.foo.toUpperCase()); // BAR
```

and it will complain if you try to use it on a subclass whose constructor requires an argument:

```
class BadSub extends Base {
    constructor(public bar: string) {
        super();
    }
}
const badSub = BadSub.find(); // error!
// ----------> ~~~~~~
// typeof BadSub is not assignable to new () => BadSub
console.log(badSub.bar.toUpperCase());  // error at runtime, badSub.bar is undefined
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck! [Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8CwAoaXoQC5lwEthoAzQgOwBMAeAFWgQA9cFqZ4IEA+AClwAWhCAC5oFBAHdovAJTQAvN2h1ZYhmkzZtAJwS4Arjorip0QcLkBuaAHpb4gPYBaMDoDm0YI4p4dB4FxHHQxtAF8MCMwMUEgYAHFHRyoAZQMAI0YWNioORBRQ7FIkxWgAInS3MqtImJ88aHck1IzSxOS09IA6cmprOwd2lvS630cQBC6QR3deJo6MnqSuoIBVAAd1hB0AYUQ5WRt7OABBACUMGPAoODBhrNZ2W64CrSxvX1x-QODedYyQMRoJUdGI-JR3PJNNptBADFsdNZClgolEPg1KvcFLdhj1KFR+sdtjpggBCDDHZxU6k05QAPwZjIpDlwAE8to5SDjOtBhE5cNA4oR3BQwOkJuZHKZpHJFMp4MNRhBxpNprNMZ0uiCVo4Ngi9lwDjYBowdCSdIKBf4KEQALYIAA0wLumpBvJgBmoCF6CCoQA)